# Object expected error in JScript when function returns integer

Tags: javascript, windows, itunes, jscript, wscript.shell

I'm trying to write a JS script for iTunes to create a playlist of any songs where the total number of songs is greater than 7 (i.e. an LP not EP). I've never written anything using Microsoft's JScript before, so a lot of this has been me learning how to use it on the fly. I don't understand why an object is expected when I just want an index value on the line: `albumKey = checkAlbumExists(albumName, albumArray);`

```
var iTunesApp = WScript.CreateObject("iTunes.Application");
var mainLibrary = iTunesApp.LibraryPlaylist;

var tracks = mainLibrary.Tracks;
// var numTracks = tracks.Count;
// limit to 100 for testing
var numTracks = 100;

var albumArray = new Array();

for (var i = 1; i <= numTracks; i++) {
  // skip track if undefined:
  if(tracks.Item(i) !== undefined) {

    // get album title from track
    var curTrack = tracks.Item(i);
    var albumName = curTrack.Album.toString();

    var albumKey = -1;
    if(albumArray.length > 0) {
      albumKey = checkAlbumExists(albumName, albumArray);

      if(albumKey === undefined || albumKey === -1) {
        // no album found
        albumArray.push({album: albumName, numTracks: 1});
      } else {
        albumArray[albumKey].numTracks++;
      }
    } else {
      albumArray.push({album: albumName, numTracks: 1});
    }
  }
}

var checkAlbumExists = function(needle, haystack) {
  for(var l =1; l<= haystack.length; l++) {
    if(haystack[l].album.toString() === needle) {
      return parseInt(l);
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
[...]
```

Any information as to what's going wrong would be really appreciated. A link to [file on my GitHub](https://github.com/JonathanMSifleet/iTunesEPPlaylistCreator/blob/main/CreateEPPlaylist.js) here in case that helps understand the fulle script in context

Comment: Do you know the difference between Java and JavaScript? Click the edit link and tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Yeah I do. I clicked the wrong link by accident